# How to best specify instance URIs in RDF?

Tags: rdf

I don't understand the implications of using `/` or `#` in the URI of an RDF class instance. For example, should I use:

- `http://helloworld.com/Person#23425` OR
- `http://helloworld.com/Person/23425`

When I populate my RDF database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C (http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/VM/http-examples/)

> Best practice dictates that all RDF vocabularies use either a hash namespace or a slash namespace (see above). Which you choose depends in part on how big you expect your vocabulary to become, how often you expect to add new terms (i.e., properties or classes), and how you expect users to access information about individual terms in your vocabulary.

What I found as a good practice and in line with the recommendation:

- `#` for ontology resources (properties and classes) and SHACL shapes
- `/` for all the rest (instance data, reference data etc)